# autocomplete and date/timepicker not working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i have an auto complete text box and 2 date/time picker in my project they work fine separately but when i merge them one doesn't work and the other work the one that works it the one with the script below the other when i interchange the script the other will work. in this example the one that will work is datepicker. i'm confused about this.what is wrong with my code this is my code http://pastebin.com/xNwZcsza

```
<!-- autocomplete -->
<link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->     
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jmobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jmobile/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jmobile/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jmobile/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two differennt versions of jQuery loaded(1.9.1 and 1.8.3), so the plugins are getting attached to two different instances of jQuery

I think the bootstrap plugin will work with jQuery 1.9 so you can remove jQuery 1.8.3 and it should be fine

```
<!-- autocomplete -->
<link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->     
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jmobile/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jmobile/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jmobile/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: @satinekianne remove `jmobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js` from the script includes

Comment: that was easy so stupid of me thank you very much.i there a way to check for this..like a site so that i wont include two same script?

Comment: can you check this script if what script are conflicting
http://pastebin.com/yW7jKuJB